# Kuberenets - Service account with cluster-admin can't access namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have created a ServiceAccount named "test-sa" under `kube-system` namespace, and created a ClusterRoleBinding that binds this service account to the `cluster-admin` role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-sa-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: test-sa
    apiGroup: ""
    namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: ""
```

When trying to execute a `helm install` command, using this service account I get the following error:

> Unable to continue with install: could not get information about the resource: serviceaccounts "test-sa-ns1" is forbidden: User "test-sa" cannot get resource "serviceaccounts" in API group "" in the namespace "ns1"

What am I missing here? as far as I know a ClusterRoleBinding should apply to all namespaces

Comment: `apiGroup` of cluster-admin role is `rbac.authorization.k8s.io`, not "" (core apiGroup). Try fixing that and applying the binding again.

Comment: @anemyte this is the yaml I am applying. When applied, the `apiGroup` is being filled automatically with `rbac.authorization.k8s.io`.

Comment: Can you check following command: kubectl create clusterrolebinding test-sa-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=test-sa ?

Comment: @Malgorzata thanks for the comment. What you suggested oddly worked for me. It seems that when specifying the subject's type to `User` instead of `ServiceAccount` that solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

All the credits I give to [@Malgorzata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11300382/malgorzata) who gave this answer...

Change `ServiceAccount` for `User`

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-sa-binding
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: test-sa
    apiGroup: ""
    namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: User
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: ""
```

I'm writing this as an answer to boost it, because I would not waste my day if I have found it earlier.